# Why is a number not transformed correctly from Windows to Unix via websphere MQ?

Tags: unix, encoding

ASCII-encoded numbers in Windows appear not to be transformed correctly on Unix, via Websphere MQ.

Here is the list in win like(Encoding.ASCII):

- 111
- 222
- ...

It turns into the following on Unix:

- ^@1^@1^@1^@^M^@$
- ^@2^@2^@2^@^M^@$
- ...

I am confused about the every char transform 'x' to '^@x'?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure it's ASCII, not Unicode?

Comment: Sure.When read the list to string I specify Encoding.ASCII.

Comment: the ^M is definitely the Windows CR char, part of a CR/LF pair, whereas Unix only requires LF (^J). Don't know what to say about the '@'s thought. Unicode sounds possible. Did you restart the application after specifying 'use ASCII' (just a guess). Good luck.

Comment: Thanks.You mean a number or char contains 2 bytes,right? I read the list using C#,so I think it doesn't matter to computer system's encode.What do you mean restart the application after specifying 'use ASCII'?Thank for your reply.

Comment: How do you get the file from Windows to Unix?

Comment: Via message queue.The file content be packaged a message, transfer to the target queue,then they(Unix) get the message from the queue.

Answer (score 0):

After research,I know put message(string) via websphere MQ without specifying a characterSet,default is Unicode.So the each char in string in Unix(UTF-8) transform 'x'(2 bytes) to '^@x'.I am not very sure about it.Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.